# Mongodb - Array indexed by string in $addToSet operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have these two documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3cdd1d0fefeba343ff3093"), 
    "country" : "C1", 
    "time" : "1994", 
    "value" : NumberInt(100), 
    "type" : "type1", 
    "origin" : "O1"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3cdd1d0fefeba343ff3094"), 
    "country" : "C1", 
    "time" : "1994", 
    "value" : NumberInt(200), 
    "type" : "type1", 
    "origin" : "O2"
}
```

I want to retrieve the aggregation with the origin array indexed by strings (the value of "type"); expected output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "country" : "C1", 
        "time" : "1994"
    }, 
    "TOT" : NumberInt(300), 
    "count" : 2.0, 
    "origin" : [
      "O1":  NumberInt(100), 
      "O2":  NumberInt(200)
    ]
}
```

Here we have the type of the "origin" array as {[key: string]: number}.
With the following query, the origin array is instead indexed by numbers:

```
use local;
db.getCollection("test_collection").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "type" : {
                    "$in" : [
                        "type1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "country" : "$country", 
                    "time" : "$time"
                }, 
                "TOT" : {
                    "$sum" : "$value"
                }, 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }, 
                "origin" : {
                    "$addToSet" : "$value"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$arrayToObject` after adding in `origin`,

```
use local;
db.getCollection("test_collection").aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": { "$in": ["type1"] } } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "country": "$country",
        "time": "$time"
      },
      "TOT": { "$sum": "$value" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1.0 },

      // add object like this
      "origin": {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$origin",
          v: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // add this
  { $addFields: { origin: { $arrayToObject: "$origin" } } }
],
{ "allowDiskUse": false }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jAwrAcIIbCg)